# How can remove CRLF in win32 edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm new to @in32 and making simple chatting app.

Now I implement edit control to write message, submit by <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but not <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>. (I want <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> to make new line.)

I made them using sub procedure.

The problem is that when I submit message by <kbd>Enter</kbd> the edit control makes a second line, and cursor point that.

[image]

I want make edit control clearly when press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Here's my code

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK SubEditProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rt = { 20,20,200,500 };
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam) {

        case VK_RETURN:
            if (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)) {
                hdc = GetDC(GetParent(hEdit));

                TCHAR buff[1024];
                GetWindowText(hEdit, buff, 1024);
                SetDlgItemText(GetParent(hEdit), ID_EDIT, (LPCWSTR)"");
                DrawText(hdc, buff, -1, &rt, DT_LEFT);

                ReleaseDC(GetParent(hEdit), hdc);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return CallWindowProc(DefEditProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling DrawText?

Comment: @Anders I need draw submitted text by Edit control.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use the [ES_WANTRETURN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles) style.